# Django send email after deleting object

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

I hope someone will be able to help. I am new in Django and struggling with sending email after using CBV DeleteView. Here is my model:

```
class  Bookings(models.Model):
    service = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    your_email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, 
           on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.your_email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('booking_list')
```

and this is my view:

```
class BookingDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Bookings
    template_name = 'booking_delete.html'
    context_object_name = 'booking'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('booking_list')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        send_mail(
            subject='CANCELLATION!!',
            message=str(Bookings.service) + str(Bookings.date) +/ 
                    str(Bookings.time),
            from_email=Bookings.your_email,
            recipient_list=['testadmin@admin.com']
        )
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Unfortunately I get only location of the data in the email, here is an example of the email received:

```
Subject: CANCELLATION!!
web_1  | From: <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at
web_1  |  0x7ff230211e50>
web_1  | To: testadmin@admin.com
web_1  | Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 14:15:29 -0000
web_1  | Message-ID: <159439052931.455.4373660896961612525@992781d7c153>
web_1  | 
web_1  | <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7ff230211df0><django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7ff230211f10><django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7ff230211d60>
```

Which is not ideal. I guess it might be something stupid that I am missing but like I said I am quite new and I have tried almost everything but nothing is working. Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use 'booking' instead of 'Bookings' that's why you passed `context_object_name = 'booking'` to the class

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply but unfortunately this solution is not working either

Answer (score 0):

After digging into it I found probably the easiest solution which was changing string representation of my model to

```
def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.service, self.your_email, self.name, self.date, self.time)
```

It is not the ideal solution but at the moment it is all I need. This way, admin will receive an email with all the information he'll need in order to know who cancelled the booking.

Many thanks for all the contributors.

Answer (score -1):

When you access to model's field thru a view, you need to retrieve the data from an instance of the model.
This will represent the attribute location:

```
Booking.<some_field>
```

i'm guessing you want to access the instance you are deleting, in that case use

```
self.<some_field>
```

let me know if it worked ;)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your swift response.I am afraid this did not work :( It says that it si invalid syntax